# How to reflect different "configurations" of a problem for training an ANN

Tags: neural-network, regression

I have a regression problem with a number of inputs. The problem also has several "configurations" which change the inputs drastically. But within the same configuration the inputs are changing much less.

Older research has dealt with the problem by training a separate neural network for each configuration. I have used the approach to one-hot encode the configuration and feed them into the neural network as inputs.

This works well, but i wonder if there might be a better way of doing this. I have only tried a multi-layer perceptron. Would a CNN, RNN, LSTM be of use to inherently separate the different configurations?

Comment: LSTM is a type of RNN. Ask yourself: how would recurrentness add anything to detecting configurations? The same applies for CNN: it won't add anything to your configuration detection, as it isn't spatial in any way. Using a MLP is the best you can do.